# How do I use an image URL in a JQuery script?

Tags: jquery, image, function, button, click

I have this code right now in place to replace some text on click, but the symbols are just huge and I tried the other smaller ones and the sizes are inconsistant. How do I put an image link in there instead of a symbol?

I want to replace the u25b2 and u25bc with image url's...

```
 $("#button").click(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
$("#label").text("\u25b2 close");
} else {
$("#label").text("\u25bc click for details");
}
});
$("#button2").click(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
$("#label2").text("\u25b2 close");
} else {
$("#label2").text("\u25bc click for details");
}
});
$("#button3").click(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
$("#label3").text("\u25b2 close");
} else {
$("#label3").text("\u25bc click for details");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image object and insert it:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://whatever.com/myimage.jpg";
$("#label2").empty().append(img);
```

---

Rather than using the image, you can control the size of the symbols you're using via CSS with `font-size` either in pure CSS or by using jQuery's `.css("font-size", xxx);` on the particular object.  In general, if a font will solve your problem, it is better than using an image (less bandwidth, less resources to load, less memory consumption, infinitely scalable to any size, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code to build image element and append that to any other element.

```js
var img = $("<img>").attr("src", "http://cdn.wallpapers.com/Images/WallPapers/previews/tn_lakesidefireworks.jpg"); // you can also add other attr here like img.attr("key","val");

$("#lbl").empty().append(img);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lbl"></div>
```